# Gannt charts in MS Project 2010

Tags: windows, architecture, charts, project-management, ms-project

Please have a look at te following image

[image]

This is a gannt chart made with MS Project 2010. I think tis chart is incorrect because if one task finishes today, the next task will begin tomorrow. This is waterfall model so one task needed to finished inorder to start the next one. I have heard that if one task finishes today, the next task need to start today.

e.g:

```
finalize proposal  - start 03/06/2013 - end 11/06/2013
indentify technologies - start 12/06/2013 - end 19/06/2013

but it should be

finalize proposal  - start 03/06/2013 - end 11/06/2013
indentify technologies - start 11/06/2013 - end 18/06/2013
```

when I add dates like that and make the dependency, MS Project by it self move the next task to **NEXT DATE**.

```
 finalize proposal  - start 03/06/2013 - **end 11/06/2013**
 identify technologies - **start 12/06/2013** - end 19/06/2013
```

why this is happening in tis way? is this chart is correct or wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chart is correct. If Task A takes one day and Task B starts after Task A is finished, Task B will start on the next day, not the same day.

This question does not belong on StackOverflow, though, since SO is for programming questions, not general software usage.